# SQL table only echoing 1 row instead of all rows

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table to fetch entries from my database however the table is only outputting the first result that it finds and not the rest of the entries in the database.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM aliases where client_id='$userid'";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
$timesused=$row['num_used'];
$alias=$row['alias'];
$firstused=$row['time_add'];
$firstused = date('d M Y H:i:s', $firstused);
$lastused=$row['time_edit'];
$lastused = date('d M Y H:i:s', $lastused);
echo "<table border=1>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<th>Alias</th>";
echo "<th>Times Used</th>";
echo "<th>First Used</th>";
echo "<th>Last Used</th>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "<tr align=center>";
echo "<td>$alias</td>";
echo "<td>$timesused</td>";
echo "<td>$firstused</td>";
echo "<td>$lastused</td>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: You need to put your `mysql_fetch_assoc` in a loop

Comment: Sorry to sound like a noob but how do I do this?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php - Example 1 shows you what to do. Also, note the large red warning about deprecation at the top of the page

Comment: the fetch functions fetch **ONE** row, so you're getting exactly what you asked for: one fetch call -> one row.

Answer (score 0):

`mysql_fetch_assoc` function returns one row from the result (you even call the variable you assign its returned value `$row`). You need to iterate in a loop on all results to get all rows, something like:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  $timesused=$row['num_used'];
  $alias=$row['alias'];
  $firstused=$row['time_add'];
  $firstused = date('d M Y H:i:s', $firstused);
  $lastused=$row['time_edit'];
  $lastused = date('d M Y H:i:s', $lastused);
    echo "<table border=1>";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<th>Alias</th>";
    echo "<th>Times Used</th>";
    echo "<th>First Used</th>";
    echo "<th>Last Used</th>";
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "<tr align=center>";
    echo "<td>$alias</td>";
    echo "<td>$timesused</td>";
    echo "<td>$firstused</td>";
    echo "<td>$lastused</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "</table>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM aliases where client_id='$userid'";
$result = mysqli_query($query);

$timesused=$row['num_used'];
$alias=$row['alias'];
$firstused=$row['time_add'];
$firstused = date('d M Y H:i:s', $firstused);
$lastused=$row['time_edit'];
$lastused = date('d M Y H:i:s', $lastused);

echo "<table border=1>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<th>Alias</th>";
echo "<th>Times Used</th>";
echo "<th>First Used</th>";
echo "<th>Last Used</th>";
echo "</tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
echo "<tr align=center>";
echo "<td>$alias</td>";
echo "<td>$timesused</td>";
echo "<td>$firstused</td>";
echo "<td>$lastused</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
    echo "</table>";
```

Just be aware that mysql_* functions are deprecated. Instead, use the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extensions.

Answer (score 0):

use while loop to display all records form table while (mysql_fetch_assoc($result)
it will display all records.